# Error when trying to install BioGeoBears package dependency rexpokit no longer on CRAN and won't install

Tags: r, installation, bioinformatics, phylogeny

I am trying to install the R package rexpokit which is a dependency for BioGeoBears. The CRAN version of the package was just removed on Oct 10, 2023.

I tried downloading and installing from the archive, but when I try to install the package I receive this error code:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rexpokit’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran -mtune=native -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c lapack/blas_mod.f -o lapack/blas_mod.o
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [lapack/blas_mod.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rexpokit’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/rexpokit’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/p2/xv7xz2mj5j5g4fkgq63w8c340000gn/T//RtmpWwCt8B/filef0277b612bc4/rexpokit_0.26.6.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Has anyone else had luck with a back door way of installing this package for BioGeoBears?

Comment: `gfortran: No such file or directory` is your culprit, what have you done for installing Fortran?

Comment: Links I found searching SO for `macos gfortran`: https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgsolve/issues/163, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639782/installing-gfortran-on-macbook-with-apple-m1-chip-for-use-in-r, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315422/cant-find-gfortran-4-8-to-build-package.

Comment: Close as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a fortran compiler. Please go through the dedicated section at CRAN for macOS https://mac.r-project.org/tools/, do everything they instruct, and please come back if none of that solves the problem.