# gfortran 4.8 error within R on OS X Yosemite

Tags: r, fortran, osx-yosemite, gfortran

I have been using [this R package for single-cell analysis (SCDE)](http://pklab.med.harvard.edu/scde/index.html) for the past few months on a Linux machine without any problems.

I have been having a lot of trouble getting it to work on my Mac, though. Installing on Mavericks seems to work fine, but I've tried on two Macs with Yosemite to no avail.

The problem seems to be with `gfortran 4.8` not playing nice with Yosemite; I get this error:

```
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c dqrdc.f -o dqrdc.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.1.1
```

Many people get this error on Yosemite while trying to use `gfortran` outside of R, and the solution they have found is to upgrade to `gfortran 5.0`, which has been fixed to work well with Yosemite.

However, R calls a specific version of `gfortran (4.8)` , so I'm kind of stuck here. I can't really upgrade to `gfortran 5.0` because R won't recognize it, and `gfortran 4.8` doesn't work well with my OS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had a clean install of Yosemite and installed XCode, XQuartz, command line tools.

Comment: But I was able to install it on two colleagues' Macs with Mavericks.

Comment: It is a not an error. It's a warning and can safely be ignored. I use that gfortran and compile R packages and have used it to create a standalone command line application in OS X Yosemite. As far as I can tell it's just a bug in gcc/gfortran. Maybe [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61407) helps .

Comment: Of course I intended to write [this discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61407).

Comment: @Bhas, unfortunately, it is in fact an error. It causes the installation of the package to fail.

Comment: H'm. As I wrote I have that warning too and a package has not failed to install. And I use compiled CRAN packages for OS X Mavericks and higher. Without more details it's not possible to find out what's the matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Homebrew, you can install gcc/gfortran 4.8 alongside newer gfortran like this:

```
brew install gcc48 --with-fortran
```

Same issue discussed in more detail here:
[OS X package installation depends on gfortran-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8)