# Installing Rcmdr/car/quantreg packages in OS X

Tags: r, macos, package

Trying to install the `Rcmdr` (R version 3.2.2) package in my Mac (Yosemite 10.10.4), I ran into a few problems:

1. After I installed Rcmdr with all its dependencies I get the following when I try to load the package:

> Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
>           Loading required package: car
>           Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ‘quantreg’
>           Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

2. So I tried to install the `car` package along with its dependency, the `quantreg` package, and this is what happens:

> ** package ‘quantreg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>           ** libs
>           gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c akj.f -o akj.o
>           make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
>           make: *** [akj.o] Error 1
>           ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quantreg’
>           * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/quantreg’
>           Warning in install.packages :
>             installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status

3. Then I realized the problem might be the fortran compiler. I don't have the 4.8 version, but I did a symlink for gfortran-4.8 to my gfortran-5.0 and yet I couldn't solve the problem:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
>           ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
>           ld: library not found for -lquadmath
>           clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>           make: *** [quantreg.so] Error 1
>           ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quantreg’
>           * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/quantreg’

I would be very grateful if someone could help me get to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: which version of R are you running?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8

Comment: I tried that before but the URL for the gfortran-4.8 was down. I tried again and, oddly enough, it worked!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it. [OSX Mojave, R 4.0.2]

I hope it helps, especially for those who could not solve it with the answers provided here: [OS X package installation depends on gfortran-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8?answertab=active#tab-top)

1. Make sure R is updated to version >= 4.0
   (for previous versions this might help: https://cran.ism.ac.jp/bin/macosx/tools/)
2. Download and install the GNU fortran compiler found here: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/
3. Make sure you add /usr/local/gfortran/bin to your PATH in order to use this compiler. This can be done, e.g. by

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gfortran/bin