# Update to version 3.3.0 gives problems with car and sjPlot

Tags: r, upgrade, r-car, quantreg, sjplot

today I upgraded to R 3.3.0... oh boy.. wish I stayed at the previous version.
The last few hours I have been trying to solve some issues to install car and sjPlot, but problems remain.
When installing sjPlot everything goes fine, but when setting the library, I get this error:

```
         error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
         there is no package called ‘quantreg’
         Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’
```

Something similar occurs with car, during installation:

```
       installing the source package ‘quantreg’

       trying URL 'https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/src/contrib/quantreg_5.26.tar.gz'
       Content type 'unknown' length 1720216 bytes (1.6 MB)
       ==================================================
      downloaded 1.6 MB

     * installing *source* package ‘quantreg’ ...
    ** package ‘quantreg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
   gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c akj.f -o akj.o
   gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c boot.f -o boot.o
   gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c bound.f -o bound.o
   gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c boundc.f -o boundc.o
   gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c brute.f -o brute.o
  /var/folders/lp/ndh7gxxs6vn0ldd3fqblq7k80000gn/T//ccbxq8DR.s:37:expecting string instruction after `rep'
  make: *** [brute.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quantreg’
 * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/quantreg’

The downloaded source packages are in
         ‘/private/var/folders/lp/ndh7gxxs6vn0ldd3fqblq7k80000gn/T/RtmpNPzXls/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("car") :
installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to solve this?? 
Thanks

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try to install quantreg directly?  I happened to have installed it today when I updated to R 3.3.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried, same message as with installing car... unfortunately

Comment: There are some hits if you search the error message that you might find useful, such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142068/installing-rcmdr-car-quantreg-packages-in-os-x) and [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/58802-package-installation-error-quantreg)

Comment: Don't install quantreg from the sources but only from older binary version if possible. Does this help? That said, I probably coild move the car package from the imports to the suggestions in my sjPlot package because the car-functions I use are only needed for plotting model assumptions.

Comment: I solved it by saying "no" to R when it asks: Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? y/n
Hope this is not going to give problems :)