# R package not loading - I think no path to gfortran?

Tags: r, fortran

So I am trying to load a package downloaded from GitHub and can't get some of the dependencies to work. When trying to load the package I get this error message:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/l   ibs/smwrStats.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/libs/smwrStats.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/libs/smwrStats.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘load flex’
```

It seems like it's having some troubles loading some dependencies, namely a package called `smwrStats` which was downloaded along with the `loadflex` package. When I try and load the `smwrStats` package, I get the same error output:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/libs/smwrStats.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/libs/smwrStats.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/smwrStats/libs/smwrStats.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘smwrStats’
```

It seems like R is not finding a path to `fortran.3.dylib` to successfully load the package? If that's the case, can someone tell me how to specify that path? If that's not the case can you tell me what in the world is wrong?

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 and R version 3.2.3. I searched around and tried to reinstall gcc with home-brew and reinstall quartz and R with home-brew, but that didn't seem to help me out at all.

Comment: The fact that you downloaded the package on Github is irrelevant.

Comment: @VladimirF actually it is relevant

Comment: Enough for tagging and mentioning in the title? How differently behave packages from Github to packages from Bitbucket? ("I am a bit of a newbie to third party packages coming from GitHub, but it seems like R...")

Comment: I appreciate the jab...not super helpful though

Comment: Found a fix here on a different thread: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8)

Comment: It's not clear what code was used or what setup was in place, but it seems likely that user5796341 doesn't understand or have the full requirements for building from source. I was going to refer him to http://r.research.att.com/libs/ but I have not been able to get a response from that site for several weeks.