# Can not install Hmisc update 4.0.0

Tags: r, compilation, gfortran, hmisc

I am having problem to install Hmisc package for R 4.0.0 because of gfortran compilation error

```
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘15.6.0
f951: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
f951: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
gfortran-4.8: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program f951)
make: *** [cidxcn.o] Abort trap: 6
```

I am running following r and mac os x

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

I have reinstalled gcc using brew and gfortran-4.8 directly. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Wait, you installed gfortran from some other source than gcc? That is not a good idea. Do you have the rest of gcc-4.8?

Comment: @VladimirF I have done it because the original was not functioning (I mean installed with Xcode and Brew). That is why I have uninstalled, after reading some comments on stack overflow. I have used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8) suggestion from stack overflow.

Comment: Highest Mac binary version of Hmisc on CRAN is 3.17-4. I also get the same error when attempting to compile from source (as does the Mac build machine.).

Comment: The new version is full of changes that I was waiting for long. That is why I would love to install it as soon as it possible. I have already written to author (Prof Harrell from Vanderbilt University) and he suggested to install it from CRAN. So lets hope there is going to be binary version for Mac OS X soon.

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar errors on Linux and solved all of them by installing the right devel packages (gmp-devel mpfr-devel libmpc-devel ..). I never had to reinstall gcc/gfortran.