# Packages Requiring Fortran in R not Working in macOS Sierra

Tags: r, macos, fortran

I am trying to use a number of R packages that rely on fortran in macOS Sierra. However, I get the following error every time I load the packages. For example:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/lpSolve/libs/lpSolve.so': `maximal number of DLLs reached...
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8/25912049#25912049) proposed solution but to no avail.

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```

I have also tried re-installing XQuartx and R but not working. I'm thinking about reverting to an earlier version of OS X unless I can figure something out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: gfortran is part of gcc, which I'd just install with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) so as not to have to bother with setting your PATH. That said, this could be some other issue entirely; that error message is opaque to me.

Comment: This was answered in R-SIG-Mac September 16, 2016 by Henrik Bengtsson.