# R: Can't install certain packages

Tags: r, rstudio

I noticed that I am unable to install a bunch of packages. It started then I was trying to install the package *carat*. I would get this long error.

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/Users/regiswengel/anaconda/lib/R/library/robustbase’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘robustbase’ is not available for package ‘ddalpha’
* removing ‘/Users/regiswengel/anaconda/lib/R/library/ddalpha’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ddalpha’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ddalpha’ is not available for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/Users/regiswengel/anaconda/lib/R/library/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/Users/regiswengel/anaconda/lib/R/library/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

installing the dependencies `‘robustbase’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘recipes’` individually beforehand doesn't work either.

I also noticed that I am unable to update the packages

- cluster
- glmnet
- maps
- PKI
- a bunch of others

I'm currently using `R version 3.3.2` and `RStudio Version 1.0.136`. I have been using R and RStudio for months and have never had an issues installing packages. I have done a bunch of searching on Google and Stack-overflow and found some solutions. None of them have worked for me.

Comment: You could try adding `dependencies=TRUE` to `install.packages`

Comment: What mirror did you choose when you ran `install.packages()`? Maybe try a different one. Run `chooseCRANmirror()` to change your default.

Comment: Tried adding `dependencies=TRUE`. I have tried `0-Cloud`, `Canada (MB)`, and  `USA (CA 1)`.

Comment: Check what dependencies are need it. Sometimes you need to install libraries in your system.

Answer (score 1):

The error in my output was

```
gfortran -fPIC -I/Users/UserName/anaconda/include -L/Users/UserName/anaconda/lib -c eigen.f -o eigen.o

make: gfortran: No such file or directory
```

I found this thread that provided me with the answer I needed.

[OS X package installation depends on gfortran-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8)