# Unable to load recipes package

Tags: r, r-caret

1. I install the `recipes` library just fine using:

   ```
   install.packages("recipes", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
   ```
2. This gives me the following error:

> ```
> Error in library(recipes) : there is no package called ‘recipes’
> ```

I having a bigger issue, I am unable to load `caret` but it seems the reason I cannot is `recipes`, so I assume if I solve the `recipes` issue I will be able to load `caret`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is impossible to replicate. You need to answer the following questions:

- What is the error message?
- What R version are you running?
- What is your system?

I tried to install with exactly the same command. Got an error of some missing dependencies, and after running this `install.packages(c("caret", "recipes", "klaR", "ipred"))` I could finally load "recipes".

Comment: thanks for the prompt response Aleh, I have tried your install.packages command with the 4 packages but I still get the same error when I try to load the library(recipes).

Comment: error message: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘recipes’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’

Comment: R version I am running: 3.3.3

Comment: System: Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 0):

os it seems I couldn't install recipes package because of gfortran-4.8 not been available in my system. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8) and now I can finally load recipes and caret. thank you