# gfortran missing when installing R packages in MacOS Catalina

Tags: r, macos, gfortran

I just upgraded my Mac to Catalina and I've been having problems installing packages.

In particular I've been getting an error that suggests gfortran might be the problem.

I'm trying to install the sf package and it requires installing classInt and units.

The first batch of error messages are as follows:

```
** package ‘classInt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c fish1.f -o fish1.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [fish1.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘classInt’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/classInt’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/classInt’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘classInt’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not sure if I have other problems further along or this failure then just causes cascading problems.

Oh I have R 3.3.2 installed.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of suggestions around, it's difficult to know what works in any given situation. Try [this thread](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgsolve/issues/163) or [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916219/os-x-package-installation-depends-on-gfortran-4-8). `brew install gcc` seems to be a common suggestion.

Comment: thanks! yeah it's a hard one to work out what might work. When I tried ```brew install gcc``` I got back ```-bash: brew: command not found```.

Comment: You need to install homebrew first.

Comment: Managed to install GCC but unfortunately didn't change anything on the R end. I don't know if I can check what version I have?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by reinstalling R. Seems to have fixed it, but now moving on to another error. Thanks for the help!